# How to remove one of multicast delegate by passing Action<T> Method or Target

Tags: c#, unit-testing, event-handling

1. Zero to many methods are added from on or more methods on classes
2. I pass a Guid as arg
3. Currently, I have subscribed the EventHandler as a wrapped action
4. When unsubscribing the Action I expect to still be able to fire the other delegates.

```
public class SomeHandler : IDisposable
{
    private event EventHandler<Guid>? _onChangedSync;
    public void AddOnChanged(Action<Guid> eventDelegate)
        => _onChangedSync += (_, arg) => eventDelegate(arg);

    public void UnsubscribeOnChanged(Action<Guid> actionEvent)
    {
        var invocations = _onChangedSync?.GetInvocationList().Cast<EventHandler<Guid>>().ToList();
        var found = invocations?.FirstOrDefault(del => del.Method == actionEvent.Method);
        _onChangedSync -= found;
    }

    public void Change(Guid clinicId)
    {
        if (_onChangedSync != null)
        {
            _onChangedSync.Invoke(this, clinicId);
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_onChangedSync != null)
        {
            foreach (var e in _onChangedSync.GetInvocationList().Cast<EventHandler<Guid>>())
            {
                _onChangedSync -= e;
            }
        }
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

This is the unit test I use.

1. Subscribe 2 separate methods/actions
2. Unsubscribe 1 of the methods/actions
3. Expect only one of them to be called
4. Currently _callCount == 2 after run test

```
public class SomeTests
{
    private int _callCount;
    private void ListenAction1(Guid arg)
        => _callCount++;
    private void ListenAction2(Guid arg)
        => _callCount++;


    [Fact]
    public void Unsubscribed_events_must_not_be_invoked()
    {
        // Given
        var testArg = Guid.Parse("54b9bfde-ef2b-4aab-b705-4c59371c0e4f");
        using var state = new SomeHandler();
        state.AddOnChanged(ListenAction1);
        state.AddOnChanged(ListenAction2);
        state.UnsubscribeOnChanged(ListenAction1);

        // When
        state.Change(testArg);

        // Then
        Assert.Equal(expected: 1, _callCount);
    }
}
```

How do I remove one of the subscribed from the EventHandler by passing the action again and comparing it with the rest of the invocations?

Comment: This is just making this unnecessarily hard on yourself.  Just use a `public event Action<Guid> Changed;` and everything will just work.  You're getting no value out of storing the handlers as different delegate types and it's costing you a ton of extra work and complexity.  With the proper event you no longer need methods to add/remove handlers; the auto-generated add/remove handlers will already be correct.  Your `Dispose` method is also unnecessary and can just be removed, even with your current approach.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Though I will still keep the Dispose, since Microsoft recommends it in my use-case (Blazor)

Comment: You dispose method does nothing of value.  I suspect you're misunderstanding whatever guidelines you're reading.  If the object needs to implement IDisposable for other reasons (such as inheriting it from another interface or base type), it can simply have an empty implementation given what's shown here.

Comment: You were right, it was the other way around. Handlers with methods from "finished" components need to dispose of the event handlers. 

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24989